# Manually formatting numbers in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, formatting, integer

I was working on a little Python challenge that was a bit more difficult than expected: format any non-negative number so `1000` turns into `"1,000"` , `10000000` into `"10,000,000"` and so forth. I managed to do it, but I find my solution not very readable:

```
def formatting(n):
    m = str(n)  # Turn it into string
    m2 = []  # Empty list that will have the split version of the final number
    for i in range(0,len(m),3):  # Iterate every three elements

        m2.append(m[::-1][i:i+3][::-1])  # Append last three numbers, second to last three numbers, etc.
        m2.append(',')  # Add a comma between loops
    m3 = ''.join(m2[::-1])[1:] # Join and drop the first element which is always a comma.
    return m3
```

This works but it isn't as nice as it could be. What can be done?

Comment: Shouldn't `m = str(m)` be `m = str(n)`?

Comment: You're right! My code wasn't in function form so I had a little typo when I adapted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points:

- Reversing the string `m` multiple times is unnecessary. Slicing can be done on the original string using correct indices. `m[::-1][i:i+3][::-1]` is equivalent to `m[-i-3:len(m)-i]`. Another approach is to traverse the indices in the reverse order `for i in range(len(m)-1, -1, -3)` and then perform slicing accordingly.
- The logic can be simplified using `str.join`. `m2.append(',')` can be omitted. And you can just do

  ```
  m3 = ','.join(m2[::-1])
  ```
- Further improvements can be achieved by using list comprehensions and traversing the string from the beginning rather than in the reverse order. Some calculation for the indices are needed:

  ```
  def formatting(n):
      m = str(n)  # Turn it into string
      num_digits = len(m)
      seg1_len = (num_digits % 3) or 3  # Calculate length of the first segment
      segments = [m[:seg1_len], *(m[i:i+3] for i in range(seg1_len, num_digits, 3))]
      return ','.join(segments)
  ```
- Python 3's built-in [formatting specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) actually supports the thousands separator. So you can just do this to achieve the same functionality:

  ```
  formatted_n = f"{n:,}"
  ```

  Or equivalently:

  ```
  formatted_n = "{:,}".format(n)
  ```

Comment: Thanks! That was quite insightful! Also didn't know about that formatting option. Would have saved me of using `locale` multiple times.

Comment: I'm not sure what you used `locale` for. According to the doc, *For a locale aware separator, use the 'n' integer presentation type instead.*

Comment: When I'm working with money data that I have to format in some specific currency, but that's totally outside the scope of this